# Pass param into SQL checksum function with Dapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper

Faced with strange problem:

```
string sql = $@"SELECT * FROM SearchLogs
                            WHERE CHECKSUM(@query) = cs_SearchTerm 
                            AND Website = @website";          

 return await Connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<SearchLog>(sql,
                param: new { query, website });
```

Record 100% exists in the database, but I got `null`. `cs_SearchTerm` is `computed, int, nullable` field. Then I tried:

```
DECLARE @term nvarchar(500)
SET @term = @query

SELECT * FROM SearchLogs
WHERE CHECKSUM(@term) = cs_SearchTerm AND Website = @website
```

But got same result. Then I tried split into two operations:

```
 private async Task<int> SqlCheckSumAsync(string query)
 {
        string sql = @"SELECT CHECKSUM(@query)";

        return await Connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sql, param: new { query }, transaction: Transaction);
 }

string sql = $@"SELECT * FROM Search_Master 
                        WHERE cs_SearchTerm = @checksum
                        AND Website = @website";

        int checksum = await SqlCheckSumAsync(query);

        return (await Connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Search_Master>(sql,
            param: new { checksum, website },
            transaction: Transaction));
```

But still got not positive result. I wonder what I doing wrong? Why I can't pass param into `SQL scalar`?

Comment: hypothesis: the data that you pre-check-summed when populating `cs_SearchTerm`: what **exact** data type is it? is it perhaps `varchar` (not `nvarchar`)? Note that `CHECKSUM('abc')`  **does not** equal `CHECKSUM(N'abc')`. If this is the problem, it can be fixed easily enough... so basically: where did `cs_SearchTerm` come from here?

Comment: also: to confirm - are you saying that the second example (TSQL only) *also* fails to find the record? if so: let's focus on getting that working first - until we can do the thing in pure TSQL, there's no chance of use doing it from a calling application. So the first thing to try is simply: `DECLARE @term varchar(500)` in that second query

Comment: well, such thing is working: SELECT * FROM SearchLogs
WHERE cs_SearchTerm = CHECKSUM('abc') AND Website = 'ICF'. I updated my question. cs_SearchTerm  is computed, int, nullable.

Comment: on a side note: it seems *really* unusual to use checksum for this; ultimately, I'd expect a non-clustered index to work just fine here, with the index creating hash-buckets that ultimately work *kinda* similarly, without the risk of false positives... just sayin'

Comment: Do you mean non-clustered index on varchar field will be similar to indexed int field?

Comment: *pretty much*, yes; the main difference is that it'll work correctly and not give false positives; currently, your data can lie - ultimately, checksum is a 4-byte hash; that **will, absolutely** have lots of collisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, this works:

```
 SELECT * FROM SearchLogs WHERE cs_SearchTerm = CHECKSUM('abc') AND Website = 'ICF'
```

So: that tells me that you computed your checksums using `varchar` inputs. This is very important, because `CHECKSUM('abc')` gives a **completely different** answer than `CHECKSUM(N'abc')`:

```
select checksum('abc') as [Ansi], checksum(N'abc') as [Unicode]
```

gives:

```
Ansi        Unicode
----------- -----------
34400       1132495864
```

By default, dapper uses `nvarchar` (because .NET strings are utf-16). So we need to tell dapper to pass that as an ANSI string; fortunately this is simple:

```
return await Connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sql,
    new { query = new DbString { Value = query, IsAnsi = true} },
    transaction: Transaction);
```

Dapper's `DbString` type allows fine-grained control over how strings are sent, including both whether they are unicode or ANSI, and whether they are fixed width (and if so: what) or variable width.

Comment: @AlexGurskiy fresh eyes; please keep in mind that if someone sees a symptom like this and immediately says "ANSI", what that means is: somewhere in the past, that person was bitten by the same problem and spent a similar number of hours banging their head on a table trying to figure it out, and the trauma stayed with them :)